# Reading unexpected values from memory-mapped file

Tags: android, nio

I'm mapping a file like this:

```
try(AssetFileDescriptor fd = mContext.getAssets().openFd("AZ_SMA.shp");
        FileInputStream shp = fd.createInputStream();
        FileChannel ch = shp.getChannel()) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
                0, ch.size());
    // do stuff with buffer
}
```

`AssetManager#openFd(...)` was originally throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed` until I added this to my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "shp"
    }
    ...
}
```

Now it opens, but I'm reading garbage.  As the file name suggests, the file is an Esri shape file.  The first four bytes of the file are supposed to be `00 00 27 0A`, and I've verified this in a hex editor.  But I'm reading them as `50 4B 03 04`, or `80 75 03 04` in decimal.

```
final byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
buffer.get(bytes);
Log.d("DERP", Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

> 08-04 12:01:53.951 12051-12267/com.chalcodes.shapefiles D/DERP: [80, 75, 3, 4]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend suggested that I should verify the length of the file.  That's when it clicked.

The `AssetFileDescriptor` returned by `AssetManager#openFd(...)` describes a block of the APK that *contains* the mapped file, not the file itself.  My original file was 13,401,744 bytes, but `buffer.limit()` was returning 15,234,522.

The solution was to change this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
    0, ch.size());
```

...to this:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
    fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
```

I'm not quite clear on the difference between `AssetFileDescriptor`'s `getLength()` and `getDeclaredLength()`, but this works.  The first four bytes are what I expected, and `buffer.limit()` returns the expected file size.